# How to stop Eclipse split vertical window scrolling the unedited window

Tags: java, eclipse

When I split the editor vertically in eclipse, I was expecting the two views of the file being edited to be independent.

But if I scroll the left page to, say, line 500 and edit the right page at line 20, eclipse unhelpfully scrolls the left page to line 20 too! Is there some setting I can adjust to stop it doing this? I'm not clear what the point of splitting the window is, if I can't see two separate parts of the same file at the same time?

EDIT: Ok, I'm on an embarrassingly old version of eclipse - `2019-09 R (4.13.0)` on mac. The behaviour appears whether I'm splitting horizontally or vertically, and I've replicated on java files and text files. I'm a bit busy to dig into it right now. Just knowing that it's not supposed to happen is enough for now. When I update to new eclipse I'll post again if I can still replicate.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in Eclipse 2023-12 with a Java file using different ways to split the editor vertically (it is unclear which way you used). Can you reproduce this also with a plain text editor? It might caused by a plugin you have installed.

Comment: Thanks @howlger, I edited my reply. Most likely just my old version of eclipse then.

Comment: I have the same issue in Eclipse 2023-12. Very frustrating. Doesnt make a difference if I use the split or clone function.

Comment: @iddo It's frustrating to hear that you're frustrated without knowing how to reproduce your issue which makes it impossible to help. Both, split and clone should show the same content, including changes that have not yet been saved. But Eclipse is an extendable platform and plugins can do whatever they want. Therefore it depends on which editor you use and which plugins you have installed.